# How to get min from two columns from SQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working on a project with laravel 8. I have this tables and columns :

```
products:
id     price
==     =====
1      1600
2      2300

vendors:
id     name
==     ====
1      Sara
2      John

vendor_product:
product_id     vendor_id     price     special_price
==========     =========     =====     =============
1              1             2000      1000         
2              1             8000      7000         
1              2             1500      null         
2              2             null      null
```

NOTE: vendor_product is a relationship table between vendors and products with belongsToMany() method and columns of price and special_price are accessible with pivot() method.

OK, So at the first, I need to convert every null value in vendor_product.price to products.price without changing in SQL (I just want to get). In this example I need this result:

```
vendor_product:
product_id     vendor_id     price     special_price
==========     =========     =====     =============
1              1             2000      1000         
2              1             8000      7000         
1              2             1500      null         
2              2             2300      null
```

Then take the row from vendor_product that has the minimum price in all of price and special_price columns and rows. In this example I must get the fisrt row because between the two columns of price and special_price and between all of rows, special_price column in the first row has the smallest value.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Any unrelated tags? <php>, <sql> and <laravel>...

Comment: Do you want the result of the last table or just the cheapest product?

Comment: @jarlh Nope! php and sql and laravel are related to my question because I said that I'm working with laravel.

Comment: @SpaceDogCS I need the cheapest product

Comment: @Morteza so you can use the first answer inside an `DB::raw()`

Comment: Then show us the relevant php, laravel and SQL code attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `join` to bring in the product price and then `order by` and `limit`:

```
select vp.*,
       coalesce(vp.price, p.price) as imputed_price
from vendor_product vp join
     products p
     on p.id = vp.product_id
order by least(coalesce(vp.price, p.price),
               coalesce(vp.special_price, vp.price, p.price)
              )
limit 1;
```